# jQuery / jQuery UI - $("a").live("click", ...) not working for tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery, jquery-click-event

So I have some jQuery UI tabs. The source code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#ranges">Ranges</a></li>
        <li><a href="#collections">Collections</a></li>
        <li><a href="#designs">Designs</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="ranges"></div>
    <div id="collections"></div>
    <div id="designs"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabs").tabs();
});
```

My problem is that I am trying to make each tab load a page into the content panel on click of the relevant link. To start with I am just trying to set the html of all the panels on clicking a link. From the code below, if I use method 1, it works for all links. However if I use method 2 it doesn't - but *only* for the links in the tabs (i.e. the labels you click to select a tab).

Method 1 (works for all links all the time, but would not be applied to links which are added after this is called):

```
$("a").click(function () {
    $("#ranges, #collections, #designs").html("clicked");
});
```

Method 2 (works for all links which are not "tabified"):

```
$("a").live("click", function () {
    $("#ranges, #collections, #designs").html("clicked");
});
```

Does anyone know why it is behaving like this? I would really like to get method 2 working properly as there may well be links which I need to add click events to which are added after the page is originally loaded.

Thanks in advance,

Richard

PS yes the function calls for `.live` and `.click` are both in the `$(document).ready()` function, before anyone says that that may be the problem - otherwise it wouldn't work at all..

Edit:

The solution I came up with involves an extra attribute in the anchors (data-url) and the following code (which outputs a 404 not found error if the page cannot be loaded). I aim to expand this over the next few weeks / months to be a lot more powerful.

```
$(".tabs").tabs({
    select: function (event, ui) {
       $(ui.panel).load($(ui.tab).attr("data-url"), function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
           switch (XMLHttpRequest.status) {
               case 200: break;
               case 404:
                   $(ui.panel).html("<p>The requested page (" + $(ui.tab).attr("data-url") + ") could not be found.</p>");
                   break;
               default:
                   $(ui.panel).html("<p title='Status: " + XMLHttpRequest.status + "; " + XMLHttpRequest.statusText + "'>An unknown error has occurred.</p>");
                   break;
           };
       });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand what you are going for but basically you want to do something once a tab is clicked?
[Here's](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-select) the docs for setting up a callback function for selecting a tab.

EDIT: Don't know if that link is working correctly, you want to look at `select` under Events. But basically it is:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Where `ui` has information on the tab that was clicked.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking into this now - can't figure out quite how to apply it to what I want to do but I am sure I will figure something out. Will post here again if I do, and mark as answer.

Comment: Are you trying to load content from other sources (AJAX) into the tab content areas? jQuery UI tabs has a method for doing that.

Comment: Yeah I've seen that - its not appropriate in this situation though as I may have a tab panel with several parts in it which all refresh when a particular tab is selected, but I don't necessarily want all of it to refresh. Does that make sense, or should I just use 1 page per tab?

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy can you post an example of one of this tab panels? That way we get a better idea of how you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I think I may have sorted it now - at least enough to be able to show something current in my interview on Tuesday. I have lots of research to do about the company in the mean time as well so can't spend too much time on it, just enough that they can see what the new interface will look like. Sure so I had some help with it - but with a bit more experience I will be able to design an interface a lot better than this. I will post the code I ended up with in my question.

Comment: Ok code added. I actually have 3 interviews next week (possibly 2 more to be arranged today) so its important that it looks impressive and, more to the point, that it works! It is not so important that it can load multiple pages into multiple places on the screen - I can do that in future. Thanks for the help by the way.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI tabs has an outstanding issue where `return false;` is used instead of `event.preventDefault();`. This effectively prevents event bubbling which live depends on. This is scheduled to be fixed with [jQuery UI 1.9](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6765) but in the meantime the best approach is use the built in select event as suggested by @rolfwaffle.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the tabs() plugin that you are using is calling `event.preventDefault();` [(Reference)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault) once it has created it's tabs.

Then it captures the click event and the bubbling stops, so it doesn't invoke your click-function. In jQuery this is done with

```
$(element).click(function(){
    // Do stuff, then
    return false; // Cancels the event
});
```

You'd have to alter the tabs() plugin code and remove this return false; statement, OR if you are lucky, the plugin might have an option to disable that behavior.

EDIT: Now I see you're using jQuery UI. Then you should check the documentation there, since it is an awesome plugin, it will do anything you want if you do the html right and pass it the right options.

Comment: That could explain it - but it doesn't explain why they work the way I want them to through method 1, but they don't work with method 2. If they work with one then they should work with the other but if jQuery UI is returning false, as you say, then neither should work, surely..?

Comment: I guess that's true. Unfortunately I don't know the specifics of the live() method.

Comment: And for the record I wasn't the one who downvoted your answer. Just so you know.